# converting php functions that deal with sessions into codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I have two functions that deal with sessions and i need to convert them into codeigniter way.I managed to do the first one
but i am stuck at accessing session array index at the second one

first function:

```
function addItem($pid,$qty=1){
$_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']=$qty;
}
```

turned into:

```
function addItem($pid,$qty=1){
    $arr=array($pid=>array('kty'=>$qty));
        $this->session->set_userdata('basket',$arr);

}
```

second function:

```
function removeItem($pid,$qty=null){
        if($qty != null && $qty < $_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']){

        $_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']=($_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']-$qty);
        }else{
        $_SESSION['basket'][$pid]=null;
        unset($_SESSION['basket'][$pid]);
        }

    }
```

how do i rewrite the second function in codeigniter way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeItem($pid,$qty=null){
        if($qty != null && $qty < $_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']){

        $_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']=($_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty']-$qty);
        }else{
        $_SESSION['basket'][$pid]=null;
        unset($_SESSION['basket'][$pid]);
        }

    }
```

Change $_SESSION TO $this->session->userdata for ex :

```
$_SESSION['basket'][$pid]['kty'] 
to 
$this->session->userdata['basket'][$pid]['kty']
```